# Call of function from main.js in render process in electron js for multithreading

Tags: javascript, electron

I try to create multithreading application on ElectronJS but I've never been used it before and stack into problem with threads.
I used threads.js https://www.npmjs.com/package/threads for multithreading instead of default worker and it good work from main.js when I call sendFile()
I have method in main.js witch create worker and get result from thread.

```
sendFile = async (text) => {
    const send = await spawn(new Worker('./src/service/sender.js'));
    const result = await send(text);

    console.log(result);
    await Thread.terminate(send);
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "XXXXX",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "XXXXXXX",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "browser": {
    "fs": false
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@electron/remote": "^2.0.9",
    "electron": "^24.3.1",
    "md5-file": "^5.0.0",
    "threads": "^1.7.0"
  }
}
```

How can I use this method in render block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the following approach, maybe somebody find it helpful as well.

I created a method which creates Worker in the main process (`main.js`) and gets a response.

```js
sendFile = async (text) => {
    const send = await spawn(new Worker('./src/service/sender.js'));
    const response = await send(text);
    await Thread.terminate(send);
}
```

In the render process (`sender.js`), I imported `ipcRenderer` and used `send()` method to send information to the main process.

```js
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron');
ipcRenderer.send('msg', 'Hello from render process');
```

and in the main process (`main.js`), I created a listener:

```js
const { ipcMain } = require('electron');
ipcMain.on('msg', (event, data) => {
    sendFile(data);
});
```